# one button to check all check boxes and un check them too

Tags: javascript, html

I have 3 check box and one button so when I click in this button all must checked and if i click again all must uncheck but it does not working I want all function inside my object like this

```js
const btn={    
btn: null,
      check: function(checked = true) {
        const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="cb"]');
        checkboxes.forEach((checkbox) => {
          checkbox.checked = checked;
        });

      },
      checkAll: function() {
        this.check();
        this.onclick = uncheckAll;
      },

      uncheckAll: function() {
        this.check(false);
        this.onclick = checkAll;
      },
    }

    btn.check();
```

```html
<body style="background-color: #0d1117; color: #6D859E">
  <div style="margin: 60px;">
    <button id="btn">Check / Uncheck All</button>

    <ul style="list-style-type: none; padding: 0">
      <li>
        <label for="c1"><input type="checkbox" name="cb" value="1" id="c1">1</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label for="c2"><input type="checkbox" name="cb" value="2" id="c2">2</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label for="c3"> <input type="checkbox" name="cb" value="3" id="c3">3</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. See [ask].

Comment: You seem to be missing some code. Your script starts with what looks like a property, but there's no preceding object or class.

Comment: does it start like  `const btn = {  check: function` ?

Comment: @GrafiCode  yes it is

Answer (score 0):

This button will check all boxes except when all are already checked, in which case all will be unchecked.

```js
const $ = s => document.querySelector(s);
const $$ = s => [...document.querySelectorAll(s)];

const checkboxes = $$('input[name="cb"]');
const btn = $("#btn");

function areAllChecked() {
  return checkboxes.every(checkbox => checkbox.checked);
}

function checkAll() {
  checkboxes.forEach(checkbox => checkbox.checked = true);
}

function uncheckAll() {
  checkboxes.forEach(checkbox => checkbox.checked = false);
}

function handleButtonClick(event) {
  if (areAllChecked()) uncheckAll();
  else checkAll();
}

btn.addEventListener("click", handleButtonClick);
```

```html
<body style="background-color: #0d1117; color: #6D859E">
  <div style="margin: 60px;">
    <button id="btn">Check / Uncheck All</button>

    <ul style="list-style-type: none; padding: 0">
      <li>
        <label for="c1"><input type="checkbox" name="cb" value="1" id="c1">1</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label for="c2"><input type="checkbox" name="cb" value="2" id="c2">2</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label for="c3"> <input type="checkbox" name="cb" value="3" id="c3">3</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```